# R-Duplicate columns in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
1   2
1   3
```

I want to duplicate each columns three times to create a matrix like this:

```
1   1   1   2   2   2
1   1   1   3   3   3
```

I dont think I can use `rep`. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your initial matrix is called `m1`, one option could be:

```
m2 <- matrix(data = apply(m1, 2, function(x) rep(x, 3)), ncol = ncol(m1)*3)
```

Comment: You don't need an anonymous function here, you can use the `...` of `apply`: `apply(m1, 2, rep, 3)`

Comment: You are right: it's not needed. But for me it's preferred: `cognitive-economy` and `expressiveness`

Comment: Thank you! Was previously using `do.call(cbind, replicate(3, m1, simplify = FALSE))` but could not get each column to duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You can use rep in this situation, just not on the matrix itself.
This does what you want:

```
mat1 = cbind(c(1,1), c(2,3))
mat2 = mat1[, rep(1:2, each=3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it with a single `rep` inside `matrix`.

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2), nrow = 2)
matrix(rep(as.numeric(t(m)), each = 3), nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
```

Depending on the size of your matrix this might be quicker than using `apply`.